# Ask for travel other countries with a Spanish residence permit

Tags: visas, schengen, spain

I'm a student in Spain, I have visa type D but expired date. I have NIE (residence permit) in Spain. I can travel from Spain to other countries but I don't know I can travel to multiple countries ? For example, Spain-Italy-France-Netherlands-Turkey-Spain.

Answer (score 5):

The Schengen rules make essentially no difference between a valid type D visa and a valid residence permit.

Either of them gives you travel rights similar to a multiple-entry short-stay Schengen visa, and time you spend in Spain under a type D visa or residence permit do not count towards your 90/180 day clock.

It is completely permitted to travel *between* other Schengen countries (or between other Schengen countries and any non-Schengen country that will let you in), as long as you abide by the 90/180 rule.

As for the particular itinerary you suggest, note that Turkey is not in the Schengen area. You'll need a [separate visa to go there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Turkey), but holding a residence permit in a Schengen country you *may* qualify for an e-Visa instead of a regular visa.